# Différence entre « C'est le samedi qu'ils organisent » et « C'est le samedi où ils organisent »

Tags: grammaire, indications-de-temps, subordonnées, conjonctions, pronoms-relatifs

Laquelle de ces phrases est correcte ? Dans quel contexte ?

> C'est le samedi qu'ils organisent leur soirée.
>
> C'est le samedi où ils organisent leur soirée.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ces deux phrases sont correctes, mais ne s'emploient pas dans le même contexte

> C'est le samedi qu'ils organisent leur soirée.

Pourrait être une réponse à « Ils organisent leur soirée dimanche ? », elle indique que la soirée sera organisée un samedi.

> C'est le samedi où ils organisent leur soirée.

Pourrait être une réponse à « C'est quel samedi ? », elle précise que parmi tous les samedis existants, celui dont il est question est celui où ils organisent leur soirée.

Comment: Merci de votre suivi

Answer (score 1):

Si la deuxième formulation est correcte, la première n'est pas juste à mon sens sous cette forme. En effet, la présence du **le** suggère qu'on ait plus d'informations sur ce samedi.

Du coup, on peut préciser la date pour que ça devienne juste ou bien ne rien mettre du tout :

> C'est **le samedi 21** qu'ils organisent leur soirée *(le implique une date précise)*.
>   C'est **samedi** qu'ils organisent leur soirée *(sous-entendu samedi prochain)*.

Dans le cas où ce serait une phrase faisant allusion à un samedi en général, la marque du pluriel me semble nécessaire pour « leur soirée » :

> C'est le samedi qu'ils organisent **leurs soirées**.

Cela signifie que chaque fois qu'ils organisent une soirée, elle a lieu le samedi.

Un exemple qui combine les deux formulations :

> — Dis-moi Pierre, pourquoi David et Paul viennent-ils nous voir samedi prochain ?
>   — Bah tu sais ! **C'est le samedi où ils organisent leur soirée.**
>   — Ah oui, c'est vrai ! Eh pourquoi ne font-ils pas ça dimanche ?
>   — Parce qu'ils ne changent pas leurs habitudes : **c'est le samedi qu'ils organisent leurs soirées.**

Comment: Le singulier me va aussi. Dans ce cas je le comprends comme « c'est *toujours* le samedi qu'ils organisent leur soirée » au sens ou il y aurait une soirée hebdomadaire chaque samedi.